# How to loop through HoA whose values are arrayref?

Tags: arrays, performance, perl, hash, reference

I want to make my script run as optimally efficient and fast as possible.  Here's how I create my HoA.

```
use strict; use warnings; open(my $fh, '<', 'file.txt') or die $!;
my %HoA;
while (<$fh>){
    $_=~ s/\r//;
    chomp;
    my @cols = split(/\t/, $_);
    my $key = shift @cols;
    push( @{$HoA{$key}, @cols );
}
```

Say that it gives the following data structure

```
%HoA = (
    'C1' => ['1', '3', '3', '3'],
    'C2' => ['3','2'],
    'C3' => ['1','3','3','4','5','5'],
    'C4' => ['3','3','4'],
    'C5' => ['1'],
);
```

Now suppose that for each key in HoA, I wanted to pass in it's value (the array) and the entire HoA into a subroutine called `compute`.

Here's how I'm currently doing it.

```
foreach my $key ( keys %HoA ) {
    compute($HoA{$key}, \%HoA);  # on the first iteration, this actually passes an aref to [1,3,3,3]
}
```

Apparently $HoA{$key} is already an array ref to each value for that particular $key.

If this is the case, is there any advantage in terms of efficiency to doing the following

```
push( @{$HoA{$key}, \@cols );
```

It yield the following data structure

```
%HoA = (
    'C1' => [ ['1', '3'], ['3', '3'] ],
    'C2' => [ ['3','2'] ],
    'C3' => [ ['1','3'], ['3','4'], ['5','5'] ],
    'C4' => [ ['3','3','4'] ],
    'C5' => [ ['1'] ],
);
```

Will this make my script run faster? And if so, in that case how do I pass the value (the array_ref) of each key into the subroutine? Once it's in the subroutine, how do I access the individual elements within an array without dereferencing the entire array_ref in the subroutine? Also, for the $hash_ref, how do I access each array_ref?

Here's how I currently have it

```
sub compute{
# takes one param: an arrayref
my ($array_ref, $hash_ref) = @_;
    for my $p ( @{ $array_ref) ) {
        # do stuff
    }
    for my $x ( values %{ %hash_ref)) {
        # do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: To make your script go faster, you need to look at the big picture first. So far, you've only looked at doing micro-optimisations. That's not going to amount to much.

Comment: profile your application first to see where the slow parts really are

Comment: But if you want micro-optimisations, why not start with those in my answer to your last question. You've ignored three of them.

Comment: @stevenl I did that. The bottleneck (the slowest part) of my script is where I'm passing the %HoA and arrayrefs into the subroutine, and then doing the calculations. I've modified my subroutine to only use references as shown above to loop through each element. I figure now the next step would be to do something about my actual data structure that I'm passing into the subroutines.

Comment: The bottleneck is something that takes 50 microseconds???

Comment: @ikegami the `s/\r?\n\z//;` and `my ($key, @cols) = split /\t/;` lines of your answer didn't work for some reason.

Comment: I assure you they do. Something else must have been different.

Comment: In the subroutine I calculate something called a Pearson Correlation Coefficient. The bottleneck (calling this subroutine) takes approx. 30-40 seconds. I would like to get it down to 10 seconds. It was at 120-170 seconds before I made switched to using array_refs and hash_refs, and other improvements.

Comment: Calling the sub doesn't tak 30-40 seconds. It takes less than 0.000,001 seconds. It's what you do in the sub that takes that long. Code you didn't show.

Comment: The subroutine is literally 40 lines long but basically I do the calculation shown on this [SITE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) in the subroutine. Scroll down to **Definition**. The formula is the first one shown under **For a sample**

Comment: **General Rule (when passing values):** ref faster than non-ref

Comment: @vol7ron, he passing a ref in both options.

Comment: Number crunching will be slow in Perl. [PDL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PDL) would probably help. Calling a C function to do that actual calculation would be fastest.

Comment: this is an assignment for a class :-P I'm not allowed to use functions from modules otherwise I'll lose points.

Comment: PDL won't find the value for you. It just a different way to do math.

Comment: @ikegami: yes, I misread one of his questions.  cooldood3490: There are other ways to loop through the array ref, w/o de-refrencing to get the upper bound of the array; however, for arrays so small, it would not be optimal, since it would require other ops to handle errors and whatnot - larger arrays could have some benefit, but I doubt it since Perl generally has internal optimizations on common commands (dereferencing being one)

Comment: @vol7ron do these ops use modules? I am working with larger arrays (of size 114).

Comment: @cooldood3490 114 is still pretty small.  This is microoptimization, and you're not going to see any noticeable difference.  If you really want to optimize, you might want to go to c or assembly; otherwise, what is the real problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @vol7ron I posted a new question.

Answer (score 1):

This will probably make your code run slower due to dereferences in your code. Further, you need to flatten the arrays contained in the array pointed by each hash entry, like so:

```
my %h = ( a => [ [1, 2], [3, 4] ], b => [ [2, 3], [5, 6] ]); 
my $key = 'a';
my @all_items;
@all_items = map { @$_ } @{$h{$key}};
```

Based only on experience, de-referencing an object (i.e., array) in Perl can be really costly so your first method using less references should be faster. But you can actually time these things. The best is to just write the code and then worry about the parts that really matter after profiling the code as a whole.

Comment: for example, in a tight loop it can increase the run-time by a constant factor.

Comment: why? what is the difference?

Comment: You might want to clarify "`$h{$key} # is a list of array refs`". Even I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: look at the update, this is what I mean and it seems to work as I expect

Comment: also I based this on this statement from OP: `push( @{$HoA{$key}, \@cols );`

Comment: yes that is my answer kind of. I am saying that what he is asking would lead to something like the code in my answer and it is bad.

Comment: @perreal: checkout [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) evaluating EXPR vs BLOCK in list context

Comment: (There was some confusion on my part, so I deleted my comments. They were true, but your answer is better than I thought. +1. This comment will self-destruct soon enough too.)

Answer (score 1):

> If this is the case, is there any advantage in terms of efficiency to doing the following
>
> ```
> push( @{$HoA{$key}, \@cols );
> ```

No. Creating the data structure correctly in the first place

```
push @{ $HoA{$key} }, @cols;    # Copies the number to the anon array.

compute($_, \%HoA) for values %HoA;
```

is better than recreating the correct data structure later.

```
push @{ $HoA{$key} }, \@cols;

compute([ map @$_, @$_ ], \%HoA) for values %HoA;  # But so does this.
```

By switching, you'd end up doing a proper superset of the work you're already doing.

---

As mentioned in comments, you're optimising the wrong thing. You said your program is taking 30-40 seconds to run. Even if you reduced the time it takes to load the file to zero, your program will still takes 29-39 seconds.

Comment: alright and if so, how do I modify my subroutine and the subroutine call so that it works? Also you mentioned in an earlier comment that Changing `map { @$_ }` to `map @$_`, will save you 100x more than removing one dereference. Should I go through my code and remove unnecessary brackets and parentheses? Will this really make my code run faster?

Comment: Oh wait, can the same key appear twice in the input file?

Comment: Re: No the same key can't appear twice in the input file. Considering that the code I have now, `$HoA{$key}` is already an array_ref so if I do `$HoA{$key} = \@cols;` in order to use it in the sub wouldn't I have to dereference it twice or at least make modifications in the?

Comment: For some reason, I was assuming the key could only be found once in the file. Fixed.

Comment: alright, so it seems like I don't need to make any changes to the data structure I've constructed. My question is to what you mentioned in an earlier comment. you said: "Changing `map { @$_ }` to `map @$_`, will save you 100x more than removing one dereference. " Is this really true? Should I go through my code and remove unnecessary brackets and parentheses? Will this make my code run faster?

Comment: I don't know the exact number, but `map EXPR,` takes longer than `map BLOCK` because `map BLOCK` creates a scope. You may or may not get benefits from using `EXPR for LIST;` instead of `for (LIST) BLOCK;` Parens don't have any effect.

Comment: I mispoke. I actually meant one **iteration** of my program (that is, one go-through of something called a k-means clustering algorithm) takes 30-40 seconds. I'll have to do do this algorithm literally hundreds of times for the dataset until the points converge.

Comment: Trying to optimise something that takes less than two minutes of something that takes two hours is not useful either.

Comment: If it takes 100 iterations for the points to converge, and each iteration takes 10 seconds. That's roughly 27 minutes to run.But if each iteration takes 40 seconds. That's an hour and roughly 7 minutes. In the subroutine I use nested loops but b/c of the nature of the assignment I don't think it can be helped. I think I've optimized as much as I could considering I can't use additional modules not already built in.

Comment: Yes, and nothing you've ever posted will have any effect on those numbers. It's `compute` that's slow. It's `compute` you need to optimise. You've spent hours of time trying to optimise something that takes less than a second.

Comment: maybe I'll try to post the `compute` subroutine tomorrow in a separate question to see if you guys can help me further optimize it. I'm pretty sure I already have.

Comment: **update**: I posted the compute subroutine in a new question.